# where to add the line break

Tags: python, function

## make a 0

```
def number0(width, height, symbol):
    toporbottom  = ("*"*5)
    middle = ("*   *")
    result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + "\n" + toporbottom
    return result


result = number0(5, 5, "*")
print (result)
```

here's what happens when I run the program:

```
*****
*   **   **   **   **   *
*****
```

I want to add line break in between middle and height to make it look like a 0 shape with a height of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `middle = ("*   *")` to `middle = "*   *\n"`. And don't use the last `"\n"` in building result.

Comment: and making result be:

`result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + toporbottom`

Comment: @maccinza I added it. Hopefully OP would have figured that out when they saw the output.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:  result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle + "\n") * height + toporbottom

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change:

- `middle = ("*   *")`
- `middle = ("*   *\n")`

and

- `result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + "\n" + toporbottom`
- `result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + toporbottom`.

**Code:**

```
def number0(width, height, symbol):
    toporbottom  = ("*"*5)
    middle = ("*   *\n")
    result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + toporbottom
    return result


result = number0(5, 5, "*")
print (result)
```

**Output:**

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

**p.s.:** now you should change the hard coded symbol `"*"` in `middle` and `toporbottom` to the function parameter `symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

you just change the present code **(1)** with **(2)** :

```
1) middle = ("*   *")
   result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + "\n" + toporbottom  
2) middle = "*   *\n"
   result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height + toporbottom
```

Thus the modified code would be :

```
def number0(width, height, symbol):
    toporbottom  = ("*"*5)
    middle = "*   *\n"
    result = toporbottom + "\n" + (middle) * height  + toporbottom
    return result


result = number0(5, 5, "*")
print (result)
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)